Projections, polars, and sections: intuition and simpler proof of duality relations?
$\newcommand{\polar}{\mbox{$\large\circ$}}$Let $K \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ be a symmetric ($K = -K$) convex compact set with nonempty interior (i.e., a convex body).
Notation: We use the (standard) notation that $K^\polar$ denotes the polar body associated to convex body $K$.
I want to understand the following relations. Let $F \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ be a subspace and $P_F$ the projection onto $F$. Then the following two relations are true:
$$
P_F(K^\polar) = (F \cap K)^\polar \quad \mbox{and} \quad (P_F(K))^\polar = F \cap K^\polar.
$$
Clearly, these two relations are equivalent, as can be seen by applying either relation to the polar body and using the fact that for a symmetric convex body $L$ we have $L = (L^\polar)^\polar$.
Question: Is there a geometric / pictorial understanding of these relations? What do they mean intuitively? I also have a proof below which uses a min-max theorem. Is there a simpler argument?
Proof: As mentioned, it suffices to show that either of the relations hold, as they are equivalent. For a symmetric convex body $L$, let $h_L$ denote its support functional. Then, by duality we have
$$
P_F(K) = \{P_F(x) : x \in K\} =\{x \in F : \inf_{y \in F^\perp} h_{K^\polar}(x+y)\leq 1 \}
$$
Note that min-max theorems imply
$$
\inf_{y \in F^\perp} \sup_{z \in K^\polar} \langle x + y, z \rangle =
\sup_{z \in K^\polar} \Big\{ \langle x, z\rangle +  \inf_{y \in F^\perp} 
\langle y, z \rangle \Big\} = \sup_{z \in F \cap K^\polar} \langle x, z\rangle = h_{F \cap K^\polar}(x)
$$
since for any $z \in F^\perp \cap K^\polar$ the infimum can be taken to $-\infty$.
Thus,
$$
P_F(K) = \{z \in F : h_{F\cap K^\polar}(z) \leq 1\} =(F \cap K^\polar)^\polar. 
$$
Taking polars on both sides, we obtain $P_F(K)^\polar = F \cap K^\polar$, as needed.

You need to be a little careful, the interior of any subspace (and subset thereof) other than the entire space is empty. Might want to consider the relative interior.

Which relation are you concerned about? (In only assumed that $K$ had an interior, not that the subspace did.)

The first one. The projection of the interior of $K$ is presumably non empty whereas the interior of a subset of $F$ is (assuming that $F$ is not the whole space).

$K^\circ$ is not the interior of $K$. It is the polar body of $K$. Does that clarify?

Ahh, my apologies. Makes sense.
